# Counting number of items between two values

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of cargo items, each with a `Quantity`, `Length`, `Width`, `Height` and `Weight`. I'm trying to produce a summary of how their dimensions are distributed (ideally taking the quantities of each into account, but that's a step beyond where I'm stuck).

I have one spreadsheet with length values in 0.1m intervals in `Statistics!A2:A302`, and I'm hoping to put the quantity for each length interval in `Statistics!B2:B302`. The quantities per item are in `'Steel plate list'!$B$3:$B$1002`, and the lengths to look at are in `'Steel plate list'!$C$3:$C$1002`.

Now, at the moment I have the following formula in `Statistics!B2` and filled down:

```
=COUNTIFS('Steel plate list'!$C$3:$C$1002, ">="&A2, 'Steel plate list'!$C$3:$C$1002, "<"&A3)
```

That works fine, gives me the number of line items that have that length, but it means that, for instance, a single 8-metre plate counts as heavily as 260 12-metre plates. Is there any way to take the quantities into account? I've thought of using a `VLOOKUP` for it, but I can't think of a way to make that work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of COUNTIFS, you should be using SUMIFS. SUMIFS works like COUNTIFS, except that it *adds* all rows which match your criteria, instead of simply *counting* them.

So your formula would look almost identical to what you currently have [the first argument passed to SUMIFS is the range which you want summed, and the following arguments alternate as being either the range to look for a criteria, or the criteria to use agaisnt that range]:

```
=SUMIFS('Steel plate list'!$B$3:$B$1002,'Steel plate list'!$C$3:$C$1002, ">="&A2, 'Steel plate list'!$C$3:$C$1002, "<"&A3)
```

As you can see, apart from changing the function from COUNTIFS to SUMIFS, all I needed to do was add the first argument referencing column B on the other sheet, which holds the quantities for each row matching all criteria.

Answer (score 0):

To sum the quantity (not sum the dimensions) of the pieces you can use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF('Steel plate list'!$B$2:$B$10>=A2,IF('Steel plate list'!$B$2:$B$10<A3,'Steel plate list'!$A$2:$A$10,0),0))
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to create the array formula.

This assumes that column A contains Quantity and column B contains Length.

The formula will show that you have how many pieces for a given dimension on the Statistic page. Example, 1 piece of 8-meter and 260 12-meter pieces.

Comment: This will work, but it is effectively just a recreation of the SUMIFS function, which was purpose-built by Excel for exactly this type of scenario. Array Formulas have drawbacks and should be avoided where possible - compared with a 'Natural Array Formula' like SUMIFS, Array Formulas need to be entered with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER [as you indicated], which can make a subsequent user accidentally wreck the formula by entering the cell and pressing tab. Also, they are more computationally intensive, and are (somewhat) harder to understand.

Comment: @Bacon, You are correct. Array formulas do have their drawbacks. I should point out that both of our formulas have a slight flaw.  We're using cell A3 in the criteria.  At the end of the list (e.g. cell A302), there will be no value in A303 to compare.  We should use "<A2+0.1" to compare.